# How to accurately define Controller name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies for the basic question, but I'm trying to create an endpoint so I can a TranslationApi in my backend via my VueJs frontend via Fetch, so I need to make an endpoint I can insert. I'm attempting to create a route to make that happen, however when I run `bin/rails routes | grep CcApiController` I receive the following error:

```
ArgumentError: 'CcApiController' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use
```

I've read the documentation linked, but I'm not managing to fix this, can someone explain where I'm going wrong here? I'll link the files I've changed below:

cc_apis_controller.rb

```
module Panel
  class CcApisController < CcenterBaseController
    def index
      run Ccenter::Adapters::Zendesk::TranslationApi.call(2116449)
    end
  end
end
```

panel_routes.rb

```
def draw_api_routes
  resources: CcApiController
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :CcApiController, only: [:index]
end
```

API method I need to create Route for:

```
def make_request
    response = Faraday.post('https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate', auth_key: '', text: @final_ticket, target_lang: 'DE', source_lang: 'EN')
    if response.status == 200
      body = response.body
      message_element = body.split('"')[-2]
      return message_element
    else
      raise InvalidResponseError unless response.success?
    end
  end
```

Comment: `resources :cc_api, only: [:index]`. Please take some time to read, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that is pretty simple.
Route names are snake_case, and match the controller's file name just omit the `_controller` suffix. In your case it is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :panel do
    resources :cc_apis, only: %i[index]
  end
end
```

For more info check this [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) and this [article](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check the docs out. However, I then receive the following error: NameError at /cc_api
uninitialized constant CcApiController, but as far I can see, everything is correct in terms of plurality and the changes you suggested.

Comment: Did you wrapped your routes with namespace panel?? and do you have a file structure `panel/cc_apis_controller.rb`? 
PS: check for my edited answer.

Comment: you're correct, however, that then results in 'uninitialized constant Panel::CcApiController'

Comment: Did you changed your controller's class name to `CcApisController` ??